# SQL working with date ranges to return data from another table to place in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with sales transaction data returning the transaction date for each sales transaction.

**NB: Transaction Date is in INT format in the database i am working from**

ORIGINAL TABLE

| Transaction Date | Order No | Order Type | Season |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-02-04 | 123456 | MOI |  |
| 2018-02-04 | 789012 | EDI |  |
| 2018-02-04 | 987654 | POS |  |
| 2018-02-04 | 235687 | POS |  |

In a separate table I have a selling season and the date range in which the selling season can be applied to a sales transaction (below is just sample data not actual table data just to demonstrate what the table will look like).

SEASON TABLE

| Season | From Date | To Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SS22 | 2018-02-04 | 2018-01-01 |
| FW21 | 2018-02-05 | 2018-01-02 |
| HO21 | 2018-02-05 | 2018-01-03 |
| SS20 | 2018-02-05 | 2018-01-03 |

The desired outcome would be in the SEASON column on the original table to pick up which season is required based on the transaction date and if the transaction falls between the FROM and TO dates in the season table

UPDATES ORIGINAL TABLE

| Transaction Date | Order No | Order Type | Season |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-02-04 | 123456 | MOI | FW21 |
| 2018-02-04 | 789012 | EDI | SS21 |
| 2018-02-04 | 987654 | POS | HO21 |
| 2018-02-04 | 235687 | POS |  |

I have no idea where to start but i did find something and was wondering if this would be the most optimized way to look at the required statement or is there something better that would work.

```
DECLARE @TRANSACTIONDATE AS DATETIME


SELECT CASE 
    WHEN @TRANSACTIONDATE  BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31' THEN 'SS22'
    WHEN @TRANSACTIONDATE  BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-06-31' THEN 'FW21'
    WHEN @TRANSACTIONDATE  BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-09-31' THEN 'SS20'
    WHEN @TRANSACTIONDATE  BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2018-12-31' THEN 'HO21'
    ELSE 'FW21?'
    END AS SEASON
```

Comment: Why would you do this? Keep information that relates to `Season` in the `Season` table, you can and should always do the lookup by date. I'd also be worried with the fact you are storing dates as `int`, you can convert them like this `DATEFROMPARTS(d / 10000, d / 100 % 100, d % 100)`

Comment: @Charlieface that was my intention.  Sorry if it i was communicated in a manner that described otherwise.  We are not storing dates in INT the ERP database does.  Yes we convert dates when required and yes i will convert the dates in the query that i am developing where i will use this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a column in the same table you can use a SQL UPDATE with a SELECT subquery to obtain the Season column value (from the [Season_Table] lookup table),
which is then updated into the Season column in the original transaction table [Transaction_Table]:

```
  UPDATE [Transaction_Table]
  SET [Season] = (SELECT Season FROM [Season_Table] s
                  WHERE s.From_Date <= [Transaction_Table].TransactionDate AND 
                        s.To_Date >= [Transaction_Table].TransactionDate)
```

This avoids having to use a CASE statement.

If using SQL server T-SQL there are many useful examples and syntax describing SELECT UPDATE at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12410533/andrew-halil your recommendation worked better than what I originally had set up to update the original table.  I now have a stored procedure set up to drop the season table and update it based on the year the season falls in and the query to update the original table using data from the season table.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a useful reference link to the post.